# A Laplace Boundary Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How exactly should I adress this problem of partial differential equations regarding laplace's equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0 $$

with the following conditions: $(x,y)$ belongs to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$,
$u(x,0)=u(0,y)=0$,
$u(x,1)=2x$,
and $u(1,y)=2y$.

Comment: This geometry is straightforwardly handled using separation of variables.

Comment: exactly how i can i do it, this is not a usual laplace problem of partial differential equations

Comment: $~$ What is $b$?

Comment: Well, since boundary data is polynomial, one can try (with fingers crossed :)) to search for a harmonic polynomial...

Comment: You can sorta guess the solution: suppose it is a polynomial, then it's a polynomial that vanishes at $x=0$, so it is a multiple of $x$, and also at $y=0$, so it is a multiple of $y$. So overall it is a multiple of $xy$. Which one is it, based on the other two boundary conditions? Is the result harmonic?

Comment: Solve one problem where $u(x,0)=u(0,y)=0=u(x,1), u(1,y)=2y$ and another problem where $u(x,0)=u(0,y)=0=u(1,y), u(x,1)=2x$. Then add the two for a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not seem to respond to the comments hinting you there:
We make a separation Ansatz
$u(x,y)=a(x)b(y)$ giving $$ba''+ab''=0$$

The simplest solution to that is $a''=b''=0$ i.e both a and b are linear, taking a look at the boundary conditions, we take $u(x,y)=2xy$ which does the trick